# How to solve y"+a²y=Sin(ax) using Method of Undetermined coefficients.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I tried solving the above differential equation using the method of undetermined coefficients as follows:-

y"+a²y = Sin(ax) ... (1)

Let yₚ=A.Sin(ax)+B.cos(ax)

yₚ'=aA.Cos(ax)-aB.sin(ax) and,

yₚ"=-a²[A.Sin(ax)+B.Cos(ax)]

Substituting the above values into (1), we get

-a²[A.Sin(ax)+B.Cos(ax)]+a²[A.Sin(ax)+B.cos(ax)]=Sin(ax)

0=Sin(ax)

which is absurd, so how do I get the correct answer using the Method of Undetermined coefficients and why is it giving the wrong answer here?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes it does !!, thanks a lot for the reference.

Comment: You might also consider taking the Laplace transform of your equation. Upon inverting the Laplace solution, you directly find the final solution that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ansatz doesn't work because it solves the homogeneous ODE. In that case you need to consider a more sophisticated ansatz, $y_p(x) = (A+Bx)\sin(ax) + (C+Dx)\cos(ax)$ should do the trick.

Comment: Why does it solve the homogenous ODE only? In other examples it seems to work, what is so particular about this case so that it doesn't work and how do I find cases like these?

Comment: Well, this method does not actually guarantee a solution, it is just an ansatz. You assume that the solution must be of this form because the RHS is of this form. But in this case the family of functions is too small to contain a solution, so you must enlarge the family of functions to look for a solution. The way you find these special cases is exactly the way you did, by trial and error (or you recognize that the whole ansatz solves the homogeneous ODE and therefore cannot solve the inhomogeneous one).

Comment: @AaryanPugarja : The idea is that if the right side is polynomial times exponential, then the particular solution is power times polynomial times the same exponential. The second polynomial has the same degree, but (as of yet) undetermined coefficients, the power has its degree equal to the multiplicity of the exponent as root of the characteristic polynomial. Sine and cosine are, via Euler formula, also representable via exponential functions with imaginary exponents. So here the exponents $\pm ia$ on the right have multiplicity one on the left, thus the factor $x^1$.